# get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and get_template_directory_uri() not returning "http"

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I've made a local copy using xampp of my wordpress website. The theme was written by me.
Locally, every image link using get_template_directory_uri() or get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is broken because it is missing the "http" prefix. If I add it manually, then the image is displayed correctly.

This is the code:
`<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/myimage.jpg' ?>`

the above functions *online* generate:
`http://www.mywebsite.it/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/myimage.jpg"`
*locally* on xampp they generate:
`localhost/myfolder/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/myimage.jpg`
and the image is not displayed. If I manually add `http://` before `localhost` it works.

Interestingly enough, the function get_template_directory_uri() is also used in functions.php to enqueue some stylesheets, and there it generates the correct url beginning with http even if locally.

I don't know hot to fix this, I don't want to change every link here locally, and having to remember to fix it back before putting it online. Sorry for my english.

Edit: I was able to automatically add "http" by escaping the url, with this code
`<?php echo esc_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/myimage.jpg') ?>`
This fixes the problem locally, and doesn't affect the output online, therefore I can sync the code like this... still, I don't know why it behaved like this.

Comment: There is something wrong here. I have used localhost many times and never had this problem. Does your site have any 'stylesheet_directory_uri', 'theme_root_uri' or 'content_url' filters added?

Comment: @user8262086 no it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Please check **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** in **Settings**